# How to convert a string ip address to [u8;4] in rust

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I am try to convert a string to array [u8;4] to use in my application. I will get the ip in string form ex "192.168.1.5". I need to convert to array of u8 = [192,168,1,5] to use it with IPAddr in RUST.

```
    let mut ip:[u8; 12] = [0 as u8;12];
    ip[..ipad.len()].copy_from_slice(ipad.as_bytes());
```

Answer (score 4):

You can parse it as an [`Ipv4Addr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.Ipv4Addr.html) and then invoke [`.octets()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.Ipv4Addr.html#method.octets) on it.  Alternatively, you may be able to just use the `Ipv4Addr` value in your application instead of using the byte array.  This better reflects the semantic meaning of the value.

```
use std::net::Ipv4Addr;

fn main() {
    let addr: Ipv4Addr = "192.168.1.5".parse().expect("parse failed");
    
    assert_eq!(addr.octets(), [192, 168, 1, 5]);
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8e20625a316324db58dc047dfe9c56d9))

Comment: HI @cdhowie , thanks for your help. I could also convert and use with an in built function. The solution is : std::net::IpAddr::from_str(&ip).unwrap()

Comment: @durgesh That means the same thing. `str::parse()` is implemented in terms of the `FromStr` trait.